# Installed the tomcat plugin but not appearing in the servers tab

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I have installed the apache tomcat plugin 9.1.2 from eclipse marketplace but the server is not showing in my "Servers" tab of eclipse and also not in the available runtimes in the

> `Windows>preferences`

It is showing as installed in the installed plugins of marketplace. Can someone please help. I am using Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: Some server plugins just add Launchers rather than Servers (the Jetty one does, not sure about Tomcat). Try looking under the Run Configurations and see if there's a new launcher section for Tomcat.

Comment: In run configurations I am not able to find one.I am not facing this issue with any other version of tomcat..would it be some issue with version 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to install the tomcat plugin. Go to the `Servers` view and right click in it's content. Then Choose `New` -> `Server`. In `Apache` you'll find Tomcat. Here you can add your installed Tomcat.

Comment: When we install a plugin, where is the apache-tomcat-v9 created ? How would I be able to add the location in the new> server installation when I am not able to locate the installation folder created

Comment: The plugin doesn't install Tomcat. You have to install Tomcat on your own.